# Convert string to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file

I am trying to do upload attachment functionality using MVC. My method that is actually doing the upload/save attachment is expecting a HttpPostedFileBase type.

```
public virtual string Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileName) 
{
     //Code to upload/save attachment.
}
```

My problem is "fileName" is being passed from the UI as a string. How can I convert the string(file path name) into something my Upload method can work with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by others, your form should look something like this:

```
<form id="form_UploadFile" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
</form>
```

Then as you mentioned you are trying to post via ajax, you can use jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to serialize the formData to be pushed to your controller.

```
$('#form_UploadFile').serialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't just pass a string from the UI, you need to upload the file from an `input type="file"`.

Comment: Do I have to do the file upload separately? what I mean is.. I am using a type = file control, but I am waiting for user to click on 'save all' button to do the save on other fields + uploading attachment from input type = file control all at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

you have to have your `<form>` tag to look like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then you will receive proper `HttpPostedFileBase` object

You may refer to this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) regarding all details.

**UPDATE**

Using ajax to submit form does not make any difference:

```cs
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourActionName", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "YourTargetId" }, new { enctype = @"multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Your inputs here
}
```

Comment: what if I am using ajax to pass values to controller?

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to use the verbose `Html.BeginForm` method?

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Attach", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    }
```

The important part is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`